# ExecuteReader returning results in random order

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm using the `ExecuteReader` command from the [`DbCommand` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute a SQL query.

The SQL query looks something like this:

```
SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C
FROM Table_A

UNION

SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C
FROM Table_B

UNION

SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C
FROM Table_C
```

When I run this SQL in SQL Server Management Studio it always returns the results in the above order, i.e. Table_A first, followed by Table_B etc.

However, when I use the `ExecuteReader()` method to execute this same query it returns the results in random order.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

EDIT: People are saying that there's no guarantee of an order in SQL, however every time I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio it comes back in the stated order.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` clause, SQL does not guarantee an inherent order.

Comment: The fact that you get the results in a particular order from SQL MS is just an implementation detail.  I am however surprised that you don't get the same order via ADO.Net.  Regardless, your query does not inherently guarantee any particular order.

Comment: If SQL Server Mgmt Studio always returns that order - it's just a lucky **coincidence**. Seriously: ***without*** an explicit `ORDER BY`, ***there is no guaranteed order*** ever ..... just add an `ORDER BY` and then you have your order!

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee that the results of this query will be in any particular order.  If you want them to be in a particular order you will need to explicitly order the results.

That you happen to notice a pattern in the ordering of the results of some operation with no defined order for its results doesn't mean that it's *obligated* to maintain that pattern in all contexts.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the query to

```
SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C, 1 As desiredOrder
FROM Table_A    
UNION    
SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C, 2 As desiredOrder
FROM Table_B    
UNION    
SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C, 3 As desiredOrder
FROM Table_C    
Order By desiredOrder
```

To ensure that you get the rows from each table in the order specified.  This however does not guarantee the order of the rows returned from each table.

Or the following to avoid the extra ordering column in the returned results.

```
SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C
FROM
    (Select col_A, col_B, col_C, 1 As desiredOrder
    FROM Table_A    
    UNION    
    SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C, 2 As desiredOrder
    FROM Table_B    
    UNION    
    SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C, 3 As desiredOrder
    FROM Table_C) As UnionQuery
Order By desiredOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem :

```
Select * from (
SELECT '0' as col_Index, col_A, col_B, col_C
FROM Table_A
UNION
SELECT '1' as col_Index, col_A, col_B, col_C
FROM Table_B
UNION
SELECT '2' as col_Index, col_A, col_B, col_C
FROM Table_C ) Table_Union
Order by col_Index
```

I sorry if can't solve your problem.

Thank.

Comment: You don't have to do the Union as a sub-query.  You can add an Order By to the end of a Union.

Comment: @juharr Both of these solutions require returning the order in a column. I believe this would be the preferred course of action if the `*` in the provided code were changed to `col_A, col_B, col_C`.